# Problem accessing data with relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, drop-down-menu

I want to create a multiple select option based on a parent select option. Here is what I have done to achieve this.

On my livewire php file:

```php
public function updatedSelectedMajor($major_id) {
    $this->skills = \App\Models\Major::where('major_id',$major_id)->with('mySkills')->get();
}
```

When I run this with this statement:

```php
@foreach($skills as $skill)
 <option value="$skill->mySkills">{{$skill->mySkills}}</option>
@endforeach
```

I get these results.

```
[{"skills_id":5,"name":"Digital Marketing","points":10,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"major_id":2,"skills_id":5}}]
```

With this I want to get only the skills_id as the value and name as the option name, but I'm getting error Property [name] does not exist. I tried with pivot, but it doesn't work either.

and when I do this:

```
<option value="$skill->mySkills[0]->skills_id">{{$skill->mySkills[0]->name}}</option>
```

it works fine, but I need to get all of the  records, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Blade provides simple directives for working with PHP's loop structures. This directive functions identically to their PHP counterpart `foreach`, for example:

```
 @foreach($skills->mySkills as $skill)

  <option value="{{ $skill->id }}">{{ $skill->name }}</option>

 @endforeach
```

Comment: this doesnt work. thats y im so much confused. it gives blank.

Comment: Check again now.
If it doesn't work that way it means that id, and name are empty.

Answer (score 0):

join table

```
use \App\Models\Major;
public function updatedSelectedMajor($major_id)
        {    
         $myvalue = $this->skills::join('major','major.id','major_id')
                   ->where('major_id',$major_id)
                   ->select('skills.*','major.myskills as myskills');
         return $myvalue;
        }
```

in blade

```
@foreach($skills as $item)

  <option value="$item->skills_id">{{$item->mySkills}}</option>

 @endforeach
```